# VNC Viewer with Username?

Tags: vnc

Does anybody know of a free VNC viewer for Windows which allows one to specify a username?  Specifically, I'm trying to find one to connect to my OS X shared desktop from Windows.  Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I just haven't been able to find one today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I have setup VNC to access a Mac (a couple of times), you just had to define an access password for the client and this got you to whatever screen was active for the current user on the Mac, so no username was needed? Happy to be corrected by Mac experts.

Comment: Hmm, looks like you're right.  I guess I mis-diagnosed the problem.  For some reason some of the clients I was trying were silently failing to connect after supplying the password, and I assumed it was an authentication problem.  I thought I remembered connecting with my actual OS X account a long time ago, but I was mistaken.  Re-setting the password on the Mac and trying again with TightVNC did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same trouble. I found one VNC client, JollysFastVNC, a Mac client, which allows you to specify a user name at login, but it's not free.