# VNC Viewer with Username for OS X? (KVMoIP)

Tags: macos, vnc, realvnc

A company gave me KVMoIP VNC details to directly connect to a Linux server which is crashing.

The details look like follows:

- Device:    http://x.x.x.x/
- Username:    user123
- Password:    ***

I've tried every possible VNC client to connect it, but I couldn't find anywhere where I can specify the username.

The only client which does work is Java VNC Viewer Enterprise Edition E4.2.6 (RealVNC). I've already tried:

- Chicken of the VNC
- vncviewer
- JollysFastVNC (also Mac auth, per this question: [VNC Viewer with Username?](https://superuser.com/questions/228758/vnc-viewer-with-username/425980))

They all doesn't work.
Any clues?

Comment: As far as I know, a username prompt isn't part of the standard VNC protocol, I think it's offered as a feature in RealVNC's paid desktop client as well but I'm not sure of compatibility without knowing the KVM manufacturer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Linux, Vinagre works flawlessly, if user name & password input is wanted on the other Linux. I recommend this only on Linux.

I tried: Real VNC, TightVNC, UltraVNC, TigerVNC and EchoVNC. I was unable to configure any of them for accepting a user name and password. (Probably you too.)

Hope this is usefull.

Comment: When using TigerVNC (xtigervncviewer) you should now be able to set a username/passwort via the environment variables `VNC_USERNAME` and `VNC_PASSWORD`, see https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc/pull/958